# передача переменной во фрагмент

Tags: android

Есть активность, адаптер и фрагмент для работы с вкладками и ViewPager. Через метод newInstance от адаптера передается переменная для работы с вкладками. Как передать еще одну переменную от активности для работы с содержимым вкладок фрагмента. Если в newInstance(int page, int nomer) ставлю два аргумента, то в адаптере ошибка  public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return (PageFragment.newInstance(position));
 т.е. в адаптере в аргументе 1 int, а во фрагменте 2.

Comment: передавайте через newInstance две переменных. Вообще, ваши объяснения без кода не очень понятны. Хороший тон прикладывать к вопросу код, который имеет к нему отношение.

Answer (score 0):

Вы изменили схему параметров метода `newInstance` добавив еще один. Соответственно, везде где этот метод используется необходимо передавать переменную. Например:

```
public void newInstance(int a, **int b**){}

newInstance(7, **0**);
```